# Logic errors get solved upon converting object to string

Tags: c#, winforms, system

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I haven't gotten any relevant results by looking up the title, and I'm not sure how else to phrase this.

I've been learning C# recently. Three times now, I've experienced a logic error that was fixed via converting an object to a string.

The first time, I was generating a random number. When I didn't convert it, I generated the same number repeatedly. When I did, the RNG worked as expected. The problem was from initializing the random variable inside the loop, instead of outside.

The second and third times involves me trying to get the first item in a list via indexing. Whenever I don't use .ToString(), the object returns null. When I do convert the item, I get the correct value. What makes it especially weird is what happens when using the debugger. When I place the breakpoint before .ToString(), the value returns null, even if I run the .ToString() line afterwards. When I place the breakpoint at or after .ToString(), the value displays just fine. In addition, I've been using a bound listbox to help me debug, and the bound listbox displays the items in the list perfectly. I still don't know what's causing these problems.

I'd like to know why this is happening. These problems are really annoying, and I'd like to avoid them in the future. If .ToString() is fixing them, then that means there's something that .ToString() does that fixes it, and I'd like to know how & why.

Sorry if any of my phrasing is wonky -- I've never been a good writer.

Update: Sorry, I didn't add the code because I wasn't sure if it was relevant or not. Here are some recreations of the error

For the RNG error:

```
        private int GenerateNumber()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int returnInt = random.Next(1, 6);
            return returnInt;
        }
        private void DisplayResult()
        {
            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            int[] displayArray = new int[5];
            foreach (int i in displayArray)
            {
                int temp = GenerateNumber();
                
                listBox1.Items.Add(temp);
            }
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            DisplayResult();
            // displays the same number
        }
```

The .ToString() "fix" is the same code, except for the `foreach` loop in `DisplayResult()`, which is changed to:

```
            foreach (int i in displayArray)
            {
                int temp = GenerateNumber();
                MessageBox.Show(temp.ToString());
                
                listBox1.Items.Add(temp);
            }
```

I can't write up the other two right now, but I will ASAP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a `Random` object inside the method. Change:

```
   private int GenerateNumber()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int returnInt = random.Next(1, 6);
        return returnInt;
    }
```

to:

```
   Random random = new Random();
   private int GenerateNumber()
    {
        int returnInt = random.Next(1, 6);
        return returnInt;
    }
```